How do I get around the Content Security Policy for a chrome extension?
I have basic extension which if you press ctrl + shift + ~ it opens a new window in which you have a menu with a bunch of tools which I use on a regular basis.
var newHTML = ``;
var map = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown', (keyPressed) => {
    switch(keyPressed.key){
        case "~":
            if(map.Control === true && map.Shift === true){
                //opens blank window with an address of about:blank
                var w = window.open('', "Menu", "width=600, height=475, scrollbars=no");
                //populates the new window with new HTML.
                w.document.write(newHTML);
            }
            break;
        case "Control":
            map.Control = true;
            break;
        case "Shift":
            map.Shift = true;
            break;
    }
});

//checks if one of the keys has been lifted
window.addEventListener('keyup', (keyPressed) => {
   switch(keyPressed.key){
        case "Control":
            map.Control = false;
            break;
        case "Shift":
            map.Shift = false;
            break;
    }
});    

The part with opening up a new window works flawlessly and I can put in basic HTML into there but the problems begin once I try to incorporate buttons. The purpose of the buttons was to be able to go between pages. I can't link the window to a server or my own website because I don't have access to one right now and I would've used links for navigation and then just done something like:
<a src="file_location">Link 1</a>
But it doesn't let me use use local files in links.
As a result I was forced to use buttons in my code and that idea got killed because whatever I do I can't get them to work. I have looked and other people have seemed to have the same problem but I can't seem to find a solution.
If I put something like:
**script.js:**
<button id="myButton">button</button>
<script src="inline.js"></script>

**inline.js:**
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click, () => {
  console.log('hi');
});

I get an error message that says:
*Refused to load the script 'https://www.linkedin.com/inlineTest.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost: http://127.0.0.1:*". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
**
I tried to ignore the CSP with a  tag:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data:; connect-src *; font-src *; object-src *;"> 
But this didn't seem to work either. I also tried using a nonce but it didn't care and kept showing me the error.
I have tried a lot of things and none of them have seemed to work, does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Not sure I read well, but it feels like you try to access a client local file from a browser. That is impossible for obvious security reasons... and that is perfect.
"But it doesn't let me use use local files in links."
So that is your answer.
"I can't link the window to a server or my own website because I don't have access to one right now"
Then work on this part.
Simple cloud servers are about 6 USD$ a month.

Thanks, I'll look into a server since it's probably the most reasonable solution.
